# DirectoryEntry.Children and Dispose

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, dispose

I'm not sure, how to free DirectoryEntry object, when I worked with it's children.
Do I need to free all childs aтd then free parent or just free parent?

For example,

```
using(DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry())
{
    foreach (DirectoryEntry childEntry in entry.Children)
    {
        ....
    }   
}
```

Is it enough?

Or need additional code such as

```
using(DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry())
{
    foreach (DirectoryEntry childEntry in entry.Children)
    {
        using(childEntry)
        {
            ...
        }
    }   
}
```

?

Comment: Not a good idea to manipulate a collection during iteration. This will (and should) probably throw an exception.

Comment: @Patrik, he is not manipulating the collection itself, just the items. Disposing doesn't remove from the collection.

Comment: foreach (DirectoryEntry childEntry in entry.Children)...

Comment: is foreach deprecated in C#, now? )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to free every enumerated child.

Moreover, you should note, that `DirectoryEntry.Children` returns newly created object every time you access its getter. This is disgustingly, because it is a rough violation of MS own guidelines (`DirectoryEntry.Children` **must** be a method), but it is true.

So:

- every time you enumerate children, you get **new** instances;
- parent entry knows nothing about created instances of enumerator, and child entries, created by enumerator.